# Run a function for each() element ordered by Id, not dom position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of words that can be rearranged in the dom and I need to grab each of them in a specific order.  I've (sort of) calculated the order I need them in and use jQuery to use that number as their Id.

My question is how do I go through each of them starting with the lowest numbered Id and ending with the highest?

The html looks something like this:

```
<span class="chosenword" id="577.9848041534424" style="position: absolute; top: 320px; left: 442.9999694824219px; z-index: 1;">Word!</span>
```

and the JS goes like this:

```
 $('.chosenword').each(function(){
   var position = $(this).position();
   var id = ((position.left) * (position.top));
   $(this).attr('id', id);
  var chosenword =  $(this).html();


   $('#chosenwords').append(chosenword);
   $('#chosenwords').append(" ");
    });
```

Note that I'm not actually grabbing the surround Span that has the Id so I can't really rearrange them after grabbing them, at least I'd prefer not to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ahh... Could you not output them to the DOM sorted to begin with? I think what you are trying to do will be very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them first, then loop with `.each()` like you're already doing:

```
$($('.chosenword').toArray().sort(function(a,b){return +a.id - b.id;})).each(function(){
   // your existing code here
});
```

Or if you cache the jQuery object you can sort it in place, which saves you having to create another jQuery object after sorting:

```
var $chosen = $('.chosenword');
[].sort.call($chosen, function(a,b){return +a.id - b.id;});
$chosen.each(function() {
    // your existing code here
});
```

Comment: jQuery puts `Array.prototype.sort` in `$.fn` - you can call `$('.chosenword').sort`

Comment: @Dennis - I didn't realise that. Thanks. Now that you've pointed it out I had a look and couldn't see it in the documentation, and in jquery.js it is under a comment "For internal use only." - so yes, it will work, but the jQuery team doesn't seem to encourage it though I would think this is a _good_ feature that they'd want to promote...

Comment: had to monkey a little with my original code but that got it, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, looking closer `$.fn.sort` would return an array, so it's not cleanly integrated into the API, but the comment for internal use only makes sense.

Comment: @Dennis - I've often wondered why the jQuery team didn't include a fully integrated `.sort()`, but then some people think jquery.js is already too big and on those rare occasions when I need to sort it's easy enough to just use `Array.prototype.sort()`, so...

Comment: I take that back.  `sort` operates in-place and returns `this`, so it is chainable with other jQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

try not to use numbers at id. In general its best if identifiers begin with a letter or underscore.

```
<div><span class="chosenword" order="1">Word 1</span> - 
<span class="chosenword" order="550">Word 550</span> - 
<span class="chosenword" order="57">Word 57</span>
</div> - 
<div id="chosenwords"></div>​
```

try sorting the array then going through each of them after you've set their order

```
$('.chosenword').each(function(){
    var position = $(this).position();
    var order = ((position.left) * (position.top));
    $(this).attr('order', order);
});

$('.chosenword').sort(sortByOrderAttr).each(function() {
   var chosenword = $(this).html() + " - ";
    $('#chosenwords').append(chosenword);
});

function sortByOrderAttr(a, b) {
    var idA = parseInt($(a).attr('order'));
    var idB = parseInt($(b).attr('order'));
    if (idA < idB) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}​
```

Comment: _"In general its best if identifiers begin with a letter or underscore"_ - Why is that? The html5 spec allows numbers, and all modern browsers support it (don't they?)...

Comment: imagine a scenario wher you might want to abstract your dom into js objects for saving in a DB or some other portable purpose. It will be much easier because numbers are not allowed to be js vars. It's also semantically incorrect for the data you're sorting on to be the 'id' of the element, you should label your data so it will make some sense out of context.

Comment: I can't imagine wanting a variable name that is the id of an element. A variable _value,_ perhaps, but not a variable _name._ If I'm abstracting the DOM into a JS object then the id would most likely end up as a property value, or possibly end up as a property name, either of which would be fine with just digits... (I do agree that `data-sort-order="..."` would be better for what the OP's doing, but that's another issue.)